# How to inherit both an implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged and the DataGrid class into a customized DataGrid class?

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance

I have created a public class SearchResultDataGrid which encapsulates various standard properties such as HasFocus, ItemSource, and SelectedItem, as follows:

```
using Notes.Interfaces;
using System.Data;

namespace Notes.Encapsulators
{
    public class SearchResultDataGrid : ObservableObject
    {
        #region Fields / Properties

        private bool _hasFocus;
        public bool HasFocus
        {
            get { return _hasFocus; }
            set 
            { 
                _hasFocus = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("HasFocus");
            }
        }

        private DataView _ItemSource;
        public DataView ItemSource
        {
            get { return _ItemSource; }
            set
            {
                _ItemSource = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ItemSource");
            }
        }

        private DataRowView _selectedItem;
        public DataRowView SelectedItem
        {
            get { return _selectedItem; }
            set
            {
                _selectedItem = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
            }
        }

        private int _selectedIndex;
        public int SelectedIndex
        {
            get { return _selectedIndex; }
            set
            {
                _selectedIndex = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedIndex");
            }
        }

        #endregion Fields / Properties

        #region Constructors

        public SearchResultDataGrid()
        {
            HasFocus = false;
            SelectedIndex = -1;
        }

        #endregion Constructors

        #region Methods

        #endregion Methods
    }
}
```

This class inherits ObservableObject (which is my implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged) so that, when instantiated, its properties can be used as Bindings to the View. However, i would also like my SearchResultDataGrid class to inherit the Systems.Windows.Controls.DataGrid class to access methods such as ScrollIntoView. I understand that C# does not support multiple inheritance. **Therefore my question is how to setup my SearchResultDataGrid class to import both INotifyPropertyChanged and the DataGrid class.** I have seen the posts on how C# does not support multiple inheritance, and have read about composition but would like to confirm what is the right direction to take to implement a solution to my question. Thanks!

Comment: Usually, the class implementing INotifyPropertyChanges is the ViewModel, and the connection to the View/Control (DataGrid) is done via WPF binding. Read about MVVM for more information.

Comment: Classes derived from DependencyObject (like any UI control class) do not implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. They declare dependency properties, which provide their own change notification mechanism. So your approach is wrong in the first place. Don't continue with it.

Comment: @Klaus Gütter : i do have INotifyPropertyChanged implemented in my ViewModel. And with the class as defined above which gets instantiated in the ViewModel, all the bindings work fine. Not sure if you (or @Clemens) are saying that i should NOT be implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in the above class: if i don't implement it but implement OnPropertyChanged in the "set" part of the variable declared as SearchResultDataGrid in the ViewModel, then none of the bindings work. Any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: OK, but it is the ViewModel, it should not derive from a Control (e.g. DataGrid)

Comment: It seems you are still trying to access a view from a view model, as in your previous question. From the comments there you should have understood that this is the wrong approach. To repeat myself, the view model should expose an event or a property where the view can attach a handler method or a data binding. When for example scrolling into view is requested by the view model, it would fire the event and the view would perform the necessary action in the attached event handler method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `SearchResultDataGrid` seems to be a custom control, it should inherit from `DataGrid` instead of `ObservableObject`.

Unike view models where you define *source* properties, controls generally don't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Your *target* properties should be implemented as [dependency properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/dependency-properties-overview?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) to provide change notifications.

That's how most of the build-in properties of the built-in controls are implemented. A target property must be defined as a dependency property for you to be able to bind anything to it, e.g.:

```
<local:SearchResultDataGrid HasFocus="{Binding ViewModelProperty}" ... />
```

Comment: thank you mm8. I think I understand your feedback. My SearchResultDataGrid is not currently setup as a UserControl: I will setup the UserControl, as well as the dependency properties. I now see that i was making a conceptual mistake. Thank you.

Comment: I would rather use `Control`, or some more derived type, as the base class.